# Ipykernel_launcher file not found on Google Colab but still throws error

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, google-colaboratory

When I run this code below:

```
torch.manual_seed(seed)
random.seed(seed)
for epoch in range(n_epochs+1):
    model.train()

    train_loss, train_loc_loss, train_class_loss  = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
    for _, (x, bb_true, class_true) in enumerate(train_loader):
        model.zero_grad()
        class_hat, bb_hat = model(x)

        batch_loss, batch_loc, batch_class = loss(class_hat, bb_hat, class_true, bb_true)
        batch_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        train_loss += batch_loss.detach().cpu().numpy()
        train_class_loss += batch_class.detach().cpu().numpy()
        train_loc_loss += batch_loc.detach().cpu().numpy()

    train_loss =  np.round(train_loss / len(train_loader), 6)
    train_loc_loss =  np.round(train_loc_loss / len(train_loader), 6)
    train_class_loss =  np.round(train_class_loss / len(train_loader), 6)

    val_loss, val_loc_loss, val_class_loss = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
    for _, (x, bb_true, class_true) in enumerate(val_loader):
        class_hat, bb_hat = model(x)

        batch_loss, batch_loc, batch_class = loss(class_hat, bb_hat, class_true, bb_true)
        val_loss += batch_loss.detach().cpu().numpy()
        val_loc_loss += batch_loc.detach().cpu().numpy()
        val_class_loss += batch_class.detach().cpu().numpy()

    val_loss = np.round(val_loss / len(val_loader), 6)
    val_loc_loss = np.round(val_loc_loss / len(val_loader), 6)
    val_class_loss = np.round(val_class_loss / len(val_loader), 6)

    _, mAP = map_eval()
    mAP = np.round(mAP, 6)

    if epoch % 5 == 0:
        print(f"----- Epoch {epoch} -----")
        print(f"Train loss: {train_loss}")
        print(f"Train loc loss: {train_loc_loss}")
        print(f"Train class loss: {train_class_loss}")
        print(f"Val loss: {val_loss}")
        print(f"Val loc loss: {val_loc_loss}")
        print(f"Val class loss: {val_class_loss}")
        print(f"Val mAP: {mAP}")
```

I can get the following error/warning and it causes my the model the stall:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:7: UserWarning: This overload of nonzero is deprecated:
    nonzero()
Consider using one of the following signatures instead:
    nonzero(*, bool as_tuple) (Triggered internally at  /pytorch/torch/csrc/utils/python_arg_parser.cpp:882.)
  import sys
```

This happens even though I'm not able to find the ipykernel_launcher.py file in the Google Colab file finder. here's a link to the notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wmyPgJ-pDAWRiyuBA40UuXDpvX2D1Vkc?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem you observe.

Comment: I updated it with a link